# GATE -Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up script

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, swingx

i am using GATE.ac.uk. scr code in eclipse LUNA java 1.8. I have problem with execution for start the GATE application.it shows the error like this:

"Error during initialisation :
gatel:util.GateRuntimeException:Could not infer installed plug-ins home!
please set it manually using the -Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up script.
Do you still want to start GATE?"

Console:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (gate.Gate).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

if you know, which version of eclipse use for GATE development let me know.
Then if you know the solution for this error & let me know the plugins(-Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up scrip)configuration steps.

Answer (score 2):

You could also define it within your code. The following example defines first the location of GateHome and PluginsHome. As kundan wrote, you can also copy the plugins dir into your project directory.

```
    if(Gate.getGateHome() == null)
        Gate.setGateHome(new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/GATE_Developer_8.2"));
    if(Gate.getPluginsHome() == null)
        Gate.setPluginsHome(new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/GATE_Developer_8.2/plugins"));

    Gate.init();

    // register the needed plugins
    Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerDirectories(new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(), "yourPlugin").toURI().toURL());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell eclipse the path to `plugins` folder which comes with the GATE installation. Here is what worked for me.

Step 1:
Copied the `plugins` folder from `C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE_Developer_8.0` to project root folder(Where `.project` and `.classpath` were present)

Step 2:
In eclipse, Right click on the project-->`Run As`-->Click on `Run Configurations`--> Goto `Arguments` tab and paste the following under `VM Argument`

`"-Dgate.plugins.home="${project_loc}\plugins"`

PS: You will also need to copy `gate.xml` and provide in `VM Arguments` in the similar way. Here is how I did it...
`-Dgate.site.config="${project_loc}\gate.xml"`